# Create a number of components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I would like to know if with sight, it was possible to call a component a certain number of times?

Basically I have a size variable that is initialized to 5 and I would like it to be 5 times the widget component.

This is my current code:

Template :

```
<template>
    <div v-for="item in size" :key="item">
        <Widget/>
    </div>
</template>
```

Script :

```
import Widget from './Widget'
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            size: 5
        }
    },
    components: {
        Widget
    }
}
```

I've looked with `v-for` but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: read the docs again, `v-for` is all explained there.

Comment: @Dan I have this error with my code : Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements.

Comment: If you wrap the `v-for` div in another div that should go away

Comment: Or you could do `<template><div><Widget v-for... /></div></template>`

Comment: @Dan Ahah that's what was wrong ! Thank you so much for your help !!!

Comment: No problem.  I turned my comment into an answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A component is allowed to have only one root element, so `v-for` on the outermost element throws an error because it would create multiple root elements.  Either of these should solve it for you:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="item in size" :key="item">
            <Widget/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

OR

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Widget v-for="item in size" :key="item" />
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fixed number of widgets you can do it by

```
<Widget v-for="number in 5" :key="number" />
```

Just keep in mind, v-for is not accepted on the root template element of a component.